# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i am getting this error please help me any one how to solve this probelm

> "_CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer", referenced from:
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Answer (score 3):

You have missed to add the framework. Make sure you have added the `CoreMedia` framework to your project.

Make sure that the missing framework is actually listed under **"Target/Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries"**. Else click `+` and add it.